# Redisson putting an ArrayList or RList inside an RMap. What will happen?

Tags: redis, redisson

Example in code:

```
map = client.getMap(...)

list = client.getList();

map.put(.., list);

...

list.add(....);

... 

thelist = map.get(...,)
```

What will happen here?

Will the list be **converted to json**, or will Redisson figure it out and use only the reference list?

Will updates to the list get reflected in the map?

What will happen if I decide to wrap the RedissonList, will my **wrapper** class be serialized to json, while the delegate list be a reference to the redis list, or will it also be serialized.

Many questions but important to get the hang of what is possible and what is not.

**map.compute** also does not seem to be locking other than locally so one has to be careful.

I suggethe implementation should override everything in java.util in their subclasses and comment or annotate (informative annotation only) to say that this method only has lcal java.util.Map works local effects.

Comment: Hi Mmm, did you get an answer on your other questions other than map.compute? e.g Will updates to the list get reflected in the map?

Comment: I think he answered below, but I moved on from that project. I don't think it is a practical lib to use. I built something superior on top of Jedis retaining full flexibility and control.

Comment: His answer seemed to be more about `map.compute` than if updates to the list get reflected in the map. That's interesting! is it opensource? Can you share?

Comment: It is not, since it takes lots of time to make sure everything is written with regards to a consistent API rather than force people to use the underlying mechanism (Jedis). As of now the functionality written to what I need personally which is a wrapper API for communicating with Jedis and in turn Redis. A bunch of things are written, map, lists, streams, queues, events, but not all functions for each. I might release it soon as opensource. Then maybe the community can fill in the blanks but too manyother priorities makes this less of a priority for me as I already have what i need.

Comment: @Enoobong I've been working on releasing a bunch of software the past week, and soon I will try to release a first version of the library.

Comment: great, looking forward

Answer (score 0):

In this case RMap value holds a reference to RList object.

> map.compute also does not seem to be locking other than locally so one has to be careful.

As stated in comment it doesn't have locking even for local map: `The default implementation makes no guarantees about synchronization or atomicity properties of this method`

Comment: Well, no, but a concurrenthashmap does, which overrides that method. If there are unsafe methods in RMap which we assume is concurrently safe, then that should either throw, or implement a version of it.

Comment: https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/3064 - done